# handling multiple devices on the play store

Tags: google-play-store, installation, multiple-devices

I have multiple Android devices, and each time I go to the play store website to install an app, I get a list of devices to install to.

my questions:

1. Is it possible to change the order of them? currently i only see how to hide (no removal? weird) or change their names ([here](https://play.google.com/settings)), but it doesn't help re-ordering them.

   I ask this since I use one of them the most.
2. is it possible to install to multiple devices at the same time instead of one by one?

Comment: As for 1) the web page usually remembers the last device selected, doesn't it? Apart from that, the answer to both is "No", as [bmdixon's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/53544/16575) correctly states.

Comment: @Izzy for 1, i wish it was, but it doesn't remember anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No there is currently no way to sort them. As you have noticed you can hide them and give them different names but not remove them. From my experience they disappear after 9 months without checking in to the play store, so simply hide any that you don't want to see.

2) Again I don't think this is possible at the moment via the Play store.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to request it from google?

Comment: You could try [contacting Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/digital-content/) (click the "Contact Us" link on that page) but i don't know if it'll get you very far.

Comment: i've tried, but i can't find out where exactly i can write anything. it's like a fully automated FAQ. it doesn't get me nowhere interesting...